# How to use add_form for Django admin?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

How can i correctly use `add_form` in admin panel when class is inherited from `admin.ModelAdmin`. I find out the hack with overriding `get_form` method where you can dynamically change `form` to `add_form` value. With current approach i'm getting this error

```
formsets, inline_instances = self._create_formsets(request, form.instance, change=False)
AttributeError: 'UserForm' object has no attribute 'instance'
```

form.py

```
class AddCustomProductForm(forms.Form):

    users = forms.ChoiceField(
        label='Select a Profile',
        required=True,
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["users"].choices = CustomUser.objects.all()
```

admin.py

```
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = ('email', 'created', 'company_id',)
    add_form = AddCustomProductForm
    form = CustomProductForm
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {"fields": ("users")}),
    )

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        defaults = {}
        if obj is None:
            defaults['form'] = self.add_form
        defaults.update(kwargs)
        return super().get_form(request, obj, **defaults)
```

Comment: I need the views.py too. Where you use the form.

Comment: there is no defined view, it is used for admin panel

Comment: I believe you can't define a form in a Model.

Comment: I see your idea, you want add a form in admin site right?

Comment: Yeah, but only when adding data

Answer (score 1):

You need a ModelForm, where you take the values directly from a Model( in this case ModelAdmin) in a form.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/modelforms/

The other way is make "your" admin panel.